# How to efficiently store locations and path efficiently and find out the shortest travel route

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, database-design

I was stuck while solving a interview question.

```
         place C

place A----------Place B


      place D
```

suppose there are 3-4 paths in which i can reach from place A to place B(direct as well as indirect path).

I had to store them and retrieve the shortest path.

I could do the the table but i couldnt select the least distance path.

I created table as below.

```
table1:
create LocationDetails(
  locnid integer primary key,
  locnname text
  );

table 2:
create PathDescription(
  pathid integer primary key,
  startlocnid integer,
  endlocnid integer,
  distance integer
  );

ALTER TABLE PathDescription
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PathDescription1
  FOREIGN KEY (startlocnid)
  REFERENCES Persons(locnid);

ALTER TABLE PathDescription
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PathDescription
  FOREIGN KEY (endlocnid)
  REFERENCES Persons(locnid);
```

But the problem now is to select a path that would cover minimum distance as
there are so many indirect paths from place A to place B.

plz help me out

thanks
regards

Comment: You've got this question tagged for three different databases. So which one are you using?

Comment: If you need to implement a path finding in a weighted graph then relational database + sql is a broken solution in the very beginning.

Comment: @zerkms: Please explain, otherwise it looks like an opinion.

Comment: @FrankHeikens graph structures don't fit well into relational DBMS, especially when you need to perform operations over it. Your answer proves that: you did not provide the pure SQL solution but a link to a postgresql extension that implements it in a programming language and the DBMS is used as a dummy storage (in that case it's no better than a plain text file).

Comment: @zerkms: No better than a plain text file? I'm pretty sure Oracle and PostgreSQL are much more than plain text when it comes to GIS and shortest path calculations. It might not be perfect, but it works in almost any case.

Comment: @Frank Heikens: well, that phrase was in the context of your answer. Eg: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html#shortest-path-dijkstra So on that page you invoke `pgr_astar` with a query to fetch the data. So virtually you're feeding the path finding function with data it keeps in memory to perform search. So - yes, I don't see how loading from a table is better than loading from a plain text file.

Comment: @FrankHeikens in this particular case a table acts as a dummy storage. My original point was: the SQL as a language and RDMBS as they are shipped by default are not perfect tools for this task: you need to power them with extensions (implemented in some *real programming language*) or switch to another kind of storage to solve the task. Is that clear enough?

Comment: sorry for tagging 3 databases.u can answer me considering postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

To choose the shortest path you should use Dijkstra algorithm, you would find a lot of infos and implementations on google.

In wikipedia there is also a pseudo code snippet : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

When using PostgreSQL, you could use PostGIS and [pgRouting](http://workshop.pgrouting.org). Shortest path calculations are well supported.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle you can use this recursive query:

```
with t(l1, l2, path, dist) as (
  select loc_id_start, loc_id_end, 'A'||loc_id_end, distance
    from paths where loc_id_start = 'A'
  union all
  select loc_id_start, loc_id_end, path||loc_id_end, distance+dist
    from paths, t where t.l2 = paths.loc_id_start )
select path, dist from t where l2 = 'E'

PATH  DIST
----- ----
ABE     11
ACE     10    <- shortest path 
ADE     14
ABCE    15
ACDE    16
ABDE    24
ABCDE   21
```

and select row(s) with minimal distance from results.

SQL Fiddle seems to be not working right now, so here is the table and data I used:

```
create table paths
( loc_id_start varchar2(5),
  loc_id_end varchar2(5),
  distance number
);

insert into paths values ('A', 'B', 7);
insert into paths values ('A', 'C', 8);
insert into paths values ('A', 'D', 9);
insert into paths values ('B', 'C', 6);
insert into paths values ('B', 'D', 12);
insert into paths values ('C', 'D', 3);
insert into paths values ('B', 'E', 4);
insert into paths values ('C', 'E', 2);
insert into paths values ('D', 'E', 5);
```